# How can $\mathbb{N}$ have an upper bound?

Tags: set-theory

"A set A is inductive if every chain in A has an upper bound."

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is a chain, apparently it has an upper bound. But how? I don't understant. How can one find a number greater than every natural number?

Comment: It would be great if you also posted the origin of this quote.

Comment: @Asaf Our instructor.

Comment: I see. It is a good practice to attribute quotes, because it also gives them context. What was the class the instructor was giving?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The bit in quotes is a definition.  Not a super common one though.

Comment: @Jim: I realized that when I first read the question. But I can give you a few definitions which when devoid of proper context will cause you to raise an eyebrow. Proper context such as *who* said that? *where* was it said? All these would appear in a proper citation format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set $\mathbb N$ with it's natural partial order is not inductive.  Indeed, you have identified a chain that does not have an upper bound.

Maybe you have confused "inductive", meaning a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound, with "a set on which you can perform induction".  The set $\mathbb N$ is certainly the latter, but not the former.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, it relies on the context.

- If we treat $\mathbb N$  as a subset of $\mathbb N$ itself, then it doesn't has any upper bound(w.r.t $\le$) since no natural number in $\mathbb N$ is greater than or equal to every natural numbers in $\mathbb N$.
- On the other hand, if we treat $\mathbb N$ as a set on the collection of all sets, then it does have upper bounds(w.r.t $\subseteq$).  One of them is $\mathbb N$ itself(note that $\mathbb N=\omega$).